# Why does pthread_join not close an array of threads properly in this example?

Tags: c, pthreads

I am trying to teach myself pthreads threading. I have the following source, which compiles and runs properly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define PTHREAD_COUNT 10
#define FREQ 5

void *thread_function(void *arg) {
  int *incoming = (int *)arg;
  int freqIdx;

  for (freqIdx = 0; freqIdx < FREQ; freqIdx++)
    fprintf(stdout, "Hello, world (thread %d)\n", *incoming);

  return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  pthread_t thread_IDs[PTHREAD_COUNT];
  void *exit_status;
  int threadIdx;

  for (threadIdx = 0; threadIdx < PTHREAD_COUNT; threadIdx++) {
    pthread_create(&thread_IDs[threadIdx], NULL, thread_function, &threadIdx);
    pthread_join(thread_IDs[threadIdx], &exit_status);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I get the following result:

```
Hello, world (thread 0)
Hello, world (thread 0)
Hello, world (thread 0)
Hello, world (thread 0)
Hello, world (thread 0)
Hello, world (thread 1)
...
Hello, world (thread 9)
```

If I `pthread_create` an array of `pthread_t` types over a loop, and then `pthread_join` in a separate loop, then things fail:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define PTHREAD_COUNT 10
#define FREQ 5

void *thread_function(void *arg) {
  int *incoming = (int *)arg;
  int freqIdx;

  for (freqIdx = 0; freqIdx < FREQ; freqIdx++)
    fprintf(stdout, "Hello, world (thread %d)\n", *incoming);

  return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  pthread_t thread_IDs[PTHREAD_COUNT];
  void *exit_status;
  int threadIdx;

  /* here I split the thread _create and _join steps into separate loops */

  for (threadIdx = 0; threadIdx < PTHREAD_COUNT; threadIdx++)
    pthread_create(&thread_IDs[threadIdx], NULL, thread_function, &threadIdx);

  for (threadIdx = 0; threadIdx < PTHREAD_COUNT; threadIdx++)
    pthread_join(thread_IDs[threadIdx], &exit_status);

  return 0;
}
```

The output from this is quite wrong. Instead of getting five `fprintf` statements from each thread, I get one or two from, say, thread 2 and 3, and about 20 to 25 `Hello, world` statements from thread 0.

Why does this fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have stated, your problem is sharing the one `threadIdx` variable between all the threads.  One way to fix this is to create one variable per thread:

```
int threadIdx;
int indexes[PTHREAD_COUNT];

for (threadIdx = 0; threadIdx < PTHREAD_COUNT; threadIdx++) {
    indexes[threadIdx] = threadIdx;
    pthread_create(&thread_IDs[threadIdx], NULL, thread_function, &indexes[threadIdx]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One issue I see is that you're giving it an address to the local variable threadIdx. When you modify it in the loop the value the thread see's is also changed. So the threadIdx value won't be correct.

In the 2nd loop you set threadIdx to 0 again and wait for threads to finish which explains why you're seeing a lot of them printing out thread 0 instead.

You can simply pass threadIdx and then interpret the void *args as an int instead (because sizeof(int) <= sizeof(void *) and is usually guaranteed on most machines) and you should get the correct output.

Answer (score 1):

You pass pointer to the same `threadIdx` variable to all threads.